# How do I rewrite the entered url to a Kubernetes Nginx ingress to reach the RabbitMQ management screen?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-aks

When I use the following yaml file to deploy my Ingress to reach the rabbitmq service, I can reach the rabbitmq management screen at . It loads correctly.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-ingress
  namespace: rabbitmq
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rabbitmq
            port:
              number: 15672
```

Now, when I change the path to "- path: /something(/|$)(.*)" and add a rewrite annotation like in the following code block, I only see this error "undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs undefined" on the /something.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-ingress
  namespace: rabbitmq
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rabbitmq
            port:
              number: 15672
```

When I run "curl -I " on the first configuration and "curl -I /something" on the second configuration, each time I receive "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".

I feel like the rewrite from /something to  is successful, so why do I get an error instead of seeing the RabbitMQ Management page?